# Serializer with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization

my question is how serializer the next string Json:

```
data:
{
  "Customers":[{"**PhoneNumber**":"123123123"},{"**PhoneNumber**":"321321321"}],
  "Expand":false,
  "Include":false
}
```

I to have doubt, because in the string JSon I  have 2 equal labels, therefore i not know as create my class with  the same labels, i'm using VB.net.

My Classes in VB.net

```
Public Class Customers
    Public as customer1
    Public expand as boolean
    Public include as boolean
End Class

Public Class customers1
    Public PhoneNumber as String
End Class
```

Comment: You need to post your development/target environment. One reply will work with web based environments but not with desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same field duplicated in this instance is okay because it is in a collection/array.  In this JSON example you have two Customer objects for the Response's Customers collection.

Your object model would look like this:

```
Public Class Response

    Public Property Customers As List(Of Customer)
    Public Property Expand As Boolean
    Public Property Include As Boolean

End Class

Public Class Customer

    Public Property PhoneNumber As String

End Class
```

An example of deserializing it:

```
Dim objSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

Dim objResponse As Response = objSerializer.Deserialize(Of Response)(strData)
```

Comment: Doesn't this require an external library from NewtonSoft - Jason.NET? If not what are the references needed to .Net?

Comment: Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization (System.Web.Extensions.dll).  Newtonsoft also provides a popular JSON serialization library.

Comment: OK - missed the project reference to `System.Web.Extensions'

Comment: NoAlias... thanks you for your  response, I will test with your information.